# Стоит ли удалять .click() и .hover() события перед удалением элементов?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем, привет!

Есть задача удалить элементы и создать другие. Как к тем, которые, необходимо удалить так и у новых элементов есть привязанные .click() и .hover() события.

Стоит ли удалять эти обработчики событий (тем же .unbind('click') например) перед удалением старых элементов и будут ли они сидеть в памяти браузера и таким образом мешать или стоит просто использовать .remove() и все остальное само удалится?

P.S. - "по возможному дубликату"
Ответ на мой вопрос полностью удовлетворил меня, а в ответе возможного дубликата не было этого, так что никакой это не дубликат, а только похожий и не более того. Мне явно виднее какой ответ для меня был полезнее. Спасибо.

Comment: не обязательно.

Comment: то есть, все привязанные события удалятся вместе с ним?

Comment: если удалится элемент к которому привязаны события, то обработчики события тоже удалятся, если они не участвуют в замыканиях и на них нет ссылок откуда-нибудь. Уже был похожий вопрос

Comment: спасибо =) 5 символов

Comment: [связанный вопрос, возможно дубликат](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/579591/186999)

Comment: не согласен, мой вопрос касается конкретно jquery-методов

Comment: в данном случае нет большой разницы

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Корректное удаление узлов из DOM, у которых зарегистрированы обработчики](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/579591/%d0%9a%d0%be%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%b7-dom-%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Comment: обновил вопрос, и никакой это не дубликат.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вы используете jQuery - то нужно запомнить что метод [`.remove()`](https://jquery-docs.ru/remove/) - удаляет сам элемент, все что находится внутри него, все данные которые связаны с этим элементом, а также все обработчики событий (`click`, `hover`, ...)

Если же нужно удалить элемент со страницы без потери всего вышеперечисленного, то следует использовать метод [`.detach()`](https://jquery-docs.ru/detach/). Это может понадобиться, например, если необходимо переместить элемент в другое место документа.

Если вы хотите скопировать существующий элемент, а также все его данные и поведение, то используйте метод [`.clone(true, true)`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/), где первый true означает копировать данные и обработчики, второй true - означает копировать данные и обработчики у вложенных элементов.

Comment: спасибо, это то что нужно =)